# fromEvent operator not firing after "Item not found search result"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

1. I search for an item
2. If the item is not found (404) i get an error as expected
3. Again if i try to search for a new item, the **fromEvent won't trigger** at all

Not sure why is that?

```
fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('qorking')),
    map((event: any) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 17 || event.keyCode === 91 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 27) {
        return;
      }
      return event.target.value;
    }),
    filter((query: any) => {
      if (!this.loading && (!query || query == '')) {
        this.searchedResult = [];
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    , debounceTime(275)
    , distinctUntilChanged() // If previous query is different from current
    , switchMap(query => {
      if (query && query !== '') {
        query = query.trim();
        this.loading = true;
        return this.cartService.searchItemByName(encodeURIComponent(query), this.shopID.shop_id.toString());
      } else {
        this.searchedResult = [];
        this.loading = false;
        return EMPTY;
      }
    }),
    // subscription for response
).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.searchedResult = [];
  let data = res.result;
  console.log('res', data);
  this.searchedResult = data;
  this.loading = false;
  if (data.length) this.setSelectedItem(data[0], 0);
}, (err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
  this.loading = false;
  this.searchedResult = [];
  this.toaster.error(err.error.message || "Something went wrong!");
})
```

Comment: When you see 404 error, is your error callback gets called which is mentioned in subscribe? I mean do you see a toastr message informing the error? Does the console.log(‘error’, err) gets executed?

Comment: @user2216584 Yes, the error callback is called & the toastr emits it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that in case of 404, your error callback gets called so, your code is doing as expected by the observable design. As per the Observable design, if an error (exception) occurs in the observable pipeline then observable is in error state and it cannot emit new values (https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) and it can be considered as completed [i.e it cannot emit new values]. Because of this reason, the `keyup` event is not triggering once the error occurred.

Now to keep the source observable live in case of error (in your case `keyup` event keep raised in case of error), handle the error in the observable which throws an error by using `catchError` operator. In your case `this.cartService.searchItemByNam` method which returns an observable. So let’s change your code like this:

```
fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('qorking')),
    map((event: any) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 17 || event.keyCode === 91 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 27) {
        return;
      }
      return event.target.value;
    }),
    filter((query: any) => {
      if (!this.loading && (!query || query == '')) {
        this.searchedResult = [];
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    , debounceTime(275)
    , distinctUntilChanged() // If previous query is different from current
    , switchMap(query => {
      if (query && query !== '') {
        query = query.trim();
        this.loading = true;
        return this.cartService.searchItemByName(encodeURIComponent(query), this.shopID.shop_id.toString())
.pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    console.log('error', err);
          this.toaster.error(err.error.message || "Something went wrong!");
          //in case of error let’s emit an empty array like you doing in other else conditions
          return of([]):
  })
);
      } else {
        this.searchedResult = [];
        this.loading = false;
        return EMPTY;
      }
    }),
    // subscription for response
).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.searchedResult = [];
  let data = res.result;
  console.log('res', data);
  this.searchedResult = data;
  this.loading = false;
  if (data.length) this.setSelectedItem(data[0], 0);
}, (err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
  this.loading = false;
  this.searchedResult = [];
  this.toaster.error(err.error.message || "Something went wrong!");
})
```

Hope it helps.

BTW, your code is having plenty of scope of improvement.

Comment: Oh! got it. Bad error handling from myside. Thank you very much it's working now. And yeah, i'm new to this & need to do lot of improvements/cleanups. Please you're welcome for any suggestions on improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're calling methods on `this` within the functions you're passing to this observable's operators, meaning that there are side effects triggered as this observable emits events.

I don't have full context on how this code changes the state of the world, but one possibility is that the element on which you're subscribing to `keyup` events is no longer on the page after the initial 404 occurs.

It's possible this would trigger no error, since the observable's just subscribed to the wrong element. But I'd need to know more about the surrounding context to say this with confidence.

Comment: @ViewChild("searchInput") searchInput: ElementRef; 


This is the input search element on which the 'keyup' event is triggered to get the list of search items. There was not issue previously. After adding "switchMap", i'm facing the issue.

Comment: If you put a tap operator with a log statement before and after the filter operator, what do you observe?

Comment: The 'keyup' event does not fire after i get a 404 response to check tap operator.

Comment: I'm not sure how simply adding a switchMap would cause an upstream source not to emit anymore. If you create a separate observable of keyup events on the element and subscribe to it, does it continue to emit after the 404?